# How to get an dynamic twitter timeline on website?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to get an dynamic timeline on a web shop. It must show tweets about the product so i have to query. But i can't find any helpful information about how to do this. I don't want to create a widget because than it's not dynamic anymore.
I tried this: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23freebandnames&count=4
But this doesn't work either.

Is it possible to do this? If it is please help me out if not than Twitter has to shame and work on this:P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose first you can to refer 
https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php

Download and include TwitterAPIExchange.php from the above mentioned GitHub repository or follow the below mention steps:

```
<?php

    include("TwitterAPIExchange.php");
    $query = "freebandnames"; 

    /** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
    $settings = array(
        'oauth_access_token' => "YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN",
        'oauth_access_token_secret' => "YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET",
        'consumer_key' => "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY",
        'consumer_secret' => "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
    );
    $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
    $requestMethod = "GET";
    $getfield = '?q='.$query.'&count=100';
    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    $result = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)->buildOauth($url,  $requestMethod)->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<pre>
    <?php echo $result;?>
</pre>
```

Comment: I got one more question for you. Now i got this working and i get a nice array in return. Now im searchin for a plugin which can turn the array in a nice looking twitter timeline but i can't find a plugin. You know one?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can have dynamic twitter feeds using widgets and single data-widget-id,just copy and paste the following code

```
    <div>
<a class="twitter-timeline"  data-widget-id="659684039234682880"  data-screen-name="yourTwitterName" ></a></div>

    <script>!function (d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https'; if (!d.getElementById(id)) { js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");

    </script>
```

for,

```
    data-screen-name="yourTwitterName"
```

to make it dynamic, you can query the twitter name from a local database when different users are logged in.
Hope this helps..!